# Experiments with Screened Lines, the diameter of the inner and outer conductor (RG174)

Tags: communication

I am refering the communication engineering related coaxial board. There they used conductive cables as RG174 and I need to find the relative permittivity, diameter of the outer conductor and inner conductor.

Diameter of the inner conductor has a value StCub 7 x 0.16 Diameter of the outer conductor has a value CuGvz

---

The diameter of the inner conductor = 0.48mm

Comment: Please provide a link to the cable's data sheet.

Comment: Hasalanka Nagahawaththa - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more information. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please **don't** use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add important technical info / clarification, please [edit] the question. (I did that for you, this time.) Or *comment* to respond to an answer or another comment with minor / trivial / temporary updates. Thanks.

Comment: As you are new here, please read the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.